# How to assign values from different dataframes for selected elements

Tags: python, pandas

I am Looking for a way to assign Elements from one dataframe to another by replacing them.

```
df1 = DataFrame({"R1": [1,2,3], "R2": [4,5,6], "R3": [7,8,9]})
df2 = DataFrame({"R1": [12,17,22], "R2": [50,55,61], "R3": [750,800,850]})
```

replace_value(x):

> *example1:*
>
> replace_value(5) = 55
>
> *example2:*
>
> replace_value(9) = 850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to specify the coordinates. See an example below:

```
ix, iy = 2, 2 # Remember Python starts counting from 0
df1.iloc[ix, iy] = df2.iloc[ix, iy]
```

Comment: Hey, how can I determine the coordinates of my object? Didn't manage to find a way and also Looking up ways to do it on SO didn't really help me that much. I found this: class MyObject:
    def _init_(self, x, y):
        self.position = Coord(x,y)

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```py
df_ = df1.melt().merge(df2.melt(), left_index=True, right_index=True,
                         on='variable')[['value_x', 'value_y']]                                           
df_ = df_.set_index('value_x')
```

output

```py
df_
Out[19]: 
         value_y
value_x         
1             12
2             17
3             22
4             50
5             55
6             61
7            750
8            800
9            850
```

```py
df_.loc[5].values
Out[26]: array([55], dtype=int64)
```